# How can I enable reasonable default caching for public files in a Grails 3 application?

Tags: java, spring, grails

I have a Grails 3 application that has images, css and js files under src/main/resources/public. These get served up with 'no-cache' headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Cache-Control:no-store
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 20 Aug 2015 06:35:30 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
```

How can I enable a more reasonable strategy for these files, especially the images? I don't want to use the asset pipeline since this is a (mostly) javascript application and we are using JS tools for bundling files and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This can be configured in application.yml:

```
grails:
    resources:
        cachePeriod: -1
```

This enables browser default caching for static resources.

The resources are served by `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler` which is configured by `org.grails.plugins.web.controllers.ControllersGrailsPlugin`. The handler supports If-Modified-Since and 304 status codes etc..

I couldn't find any mention of this in the docs.